# why does my scrollTop for detecting when I scroll to the bottom of the page not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I am currently using some js to detect when I get to the bottom of the page on a site I am developing. I am currently testing the js out with this script here:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() ){
    console.log('you are at the bottom');
  }
});
```

My issue here is that it only fires when I get to the top of my scrolled page not the bottom which was not the desired effect I wanted.

Can anyone see why its not working?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnuze/

Answer (score 0):

Because scrollTop is the top of your window, and when you reach the bottom of the page, this is not inline with the bottom.

You need to account for the window height.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    alert("bottom!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats strange because that only works when I scroll to the top.

Comment: Do you have it inside $(window).load(function(){      }); ?

Comment: Well, this jQuery is correct, I have it up and running here, so I would suggest enclosing it in window.load, moving the code to the bottom of the page etc.. I cannot help you more without seeing your markup.